# Elememtary class iff it is compact

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

A class of models $K$ is compact if for all set of formulas $\Gamma$ it holds that, if for all finite subset $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$ there exists $m_0\in K$ such that $m_0\models\Gamma_0$, then there exists $m\in K$ such that $m\models\Gamma$.

Clearly, every elementary class is compact but, is it true the converse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not. For example, a class consisting of a single infinite structure is compact (in your sense) but not elementary.

Comment: Also trivially the class containing one structure for each complete first order theory in the given language. Even if you allow parameters, a class consisting of chains of increasingly saturated models of each theory will do, I think.

Comment: @tomasz I think this might be worth its own answer, because allowing the addition of constants is a natural extension (it even interpretation) of the question, given that OP leaves the language a bit vague.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Allowing parameters doesn't make a class consisting of a single infinite structure elementary; elementary classes with infinite members have arbitrarily large members.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree, I was talking about constants (and didn't claim anything about a class being elementary), which is of course exactly how you get arbitrarily large structures in an elementary class (if it contains at least one infinite structure).